# object doesn't support property or method 'search' ie11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have a function in my javascript  which is working fine in ie8 but not in ie11. Couldn't understand why it's giving me the error. While debugging it says"object doesn't support property or method 'search'" . Please suggest something. The fine named displayDetails.js and has code like this:

```
function displayTerm(paymentDropDownId) {

  var locPaymentTypeId = null
  var index = null;

  if (null == paymentDropDownId) {
    locPaymentTypeId = this.id;
  } else {
    locPaymentTypeId = paymentDropDownId;
  }

  if (null != locPaymentTypeId) {
    if (locPaymentTypeId.search("1") > 0) {
      index = 0;
    } else if(locPaymentTypeId.search("2") > 0) {
      index = 1;
    } else if(locPaymentTypeId.search("3") > 0) {
      index = 2;
    }
  }
}
```

Calling it like-
   displayTerm(paymentDropDownId);
And 
    locPaymentOptions.onchange = displayTerm();

Comment: Either you end up with `null`, or `paymentDropDownId` is an object, not a string, and neither has a `search` method.

Comment: Well : `locPaymentOptions.onchange = displayTerm(); ` is wrong....